# How do I change the custom taxonomy slug to be the same as the custom post type slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am creating a WordPress site with a Products page, and I'm using a Custom Post Type to create the products to display under this page.

Here is a sample of the product structure I have created:

**Products (top-level page)**

- Tools (as a parent products post type)

  - Bars
  - Cleaners
  - Connectors
  - Joints
  - Punches
  - Valves
- Structures

  - Tents
  - Fences
- Materials
- Accessories

Some of these products will need to be available on a taxonomy archive page using multiple categories. For example, the 'Bars' product will have 'Milling', 'Production' and 'Retrieval' as categories. The 'Cleaners' product will have 'Retrieval' as a category. Punches will have 'Milling' as a category.

I have set up a Custom Taxonomy for my Products post type with the following structure (using `taxonomy-product_categories.php` for the archive page):

- Tools (as a parent product_categories taxonomy)

  - Milling
  - Production
  - Retrieval

I would like the URLs to look like this:

```
example.com/products/tools          (for 'tools' product post type)
example.com/products/tools/bars     (for 'bars' product post type)
example.com/products/milling        (for 'milling' product_categories taxonomy)
```

Here is the setup for my custom post type and taxonomy:

```
function create_posttype() {

    // register products post type
    $product_labels = array(
        'name'               => __( 'Products', '__x__' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Product', '__x__' ),
    );
    $product_args = array(
        'labels' => $product_labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'with_front' => false ),
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'excerpt'), 
    );
    register_post_type( 'products', $product_args );

    // register product taxonomy
    $taxonomy_product_category_args = array(
        'labels'            => array(
            'name'                       => __( 'Product Categories', '__x__' ),
            'singular_name'              => __( 'Product Category', '__x__' ),
        ),
        'public'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true, 
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'with_front' => false ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'product_categories', 'products', $taxonomy_product_category_args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

This results in URLs that look like this:

```
example.com/products/tools                      (for 'tools' product post type)
example.com/products/tools/bars                 (for 'bars' product post type)
example.com/product_categories/tools/milling    (for 'milling' product_categories taxonomy)
```

I have tried using `'slug' => 'products'` as a rewrite argument for the taxonomy, which returns a 404 error when trying to access the taxonomy archive page (I have been religious about flushing rewrite rules by saving the Permalinks Settings page).

I have read at least 20 to 30 posts here on this site, the WordPress Codex, and various blogs. I have tried various combinations of add_rewrite_rule and add_filter (term_link/generate_rewrite_rules/rewrite_rules_array). The closest I came was using this code (which does rewrite the 'product_categories' slug to 'products', but again generates a 404 error, even after flushing rewrite rules on the Permalinks Settings page):

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'change_product_categories', 10, 2 );
function change_product_categories( $permalink, $term ) {
    if ($term->taxonomy == 'product_categories') $permalink = str_replace('product_categories', 'products', $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}
```

How can I get the 'product_categories' slug to appear as the 'products' slug without throwing a 404 error?

Apologies for the long question, I just wanted to provide as much relevant detail as I could. Many thanks in advance!